# Why would .on() work but .listenTo() fail?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am working on a backbone project and inside of the initialize function of a view, I am trying to set a listener on a collection, like so:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, "change:attr", this.render)
```

However this is not catching the event. What is extremely confusing is that this actually works in its place:

```
this.collection.on("change:attr", this.render);
```

Does anyone know why this might happen? If I have to, I'll just use `on` but I'd much rather take advantage of the `listenTo` method.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Please see my answer below for additional information about the circumstances of this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out what the problem is (sort of) and am not sure if this question should be closed... but figured I would share this in case anyone has the same problem and it doesn't get closed.

In a subview of the original view, I had an event hash that looks like the following:

```
// ...in subview definition
events: {
    'keyup input': 'changeAttr'
},
changeAttr: function(){
    var value = this.$('input').val();
    this.model.set('attr', value); // this.model is in the collection
}
```

With this setup, this was working:

```
// inside parent_view:
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('change:attr', function(){ alert("changed") });
}
```

...But this was failing:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo('change:attr', function() { alert("changed") });
}
```

What I failed to mention was that I was simulating the 'keyup' event on the subview using jQuery, eg. `$('input').trigger('keyup')` (this was for automated testing purposes). For some reason that I'm not quite clear of, Backbone does not like this. What's more strange still is that the attribute would actually change! Hence the `on` method above working... Perhaps someone out there can explain to me why this is the case (perhaps some attribute of the keyup event is missing and listenTo doesn't like that?)

Comment: Never encountered this before but curious on what Backbone version you're using? Is there any error thrown at all?